# Pega Unit Testing

Tags: pega

Which two conditions do you test with a unit test? (Choose Two)

```
A . A data page populates without any errors.

B . A property value is set correctly by a data transform.

C . An application displays user views for 20 users within three
seconds.

D . An application is successfully migrated to a test system.
```

My answer is A and C. Can someone confirm it, and If different please explain.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: I think you are talking about Pega unit tests. Try creating one on your own. Then you will get the answer and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A & B can be tested using Pega Unit tests